# The schema caching in Yii

Tags: php, caching, yii

Here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.performance we can see the following information:

"*If the application is using Active Record, we should turn on the schema caching to save the time of parsing database schema. This can be done by configuring the `CDbConnection::schemaCachingDuration property to be a value greater than 0.`*"

I have some questions for it:

**1. Why should we use schema caching?**

**2. How does schema caching work?**

**3. Where can I see the tests?**

Comment: Could you clarify the first question?

Comment: @topher I mean why we should use this caching. First question related to second and third.

Answer (score 6):

If you set Yii to log database queries (`'enableParamLogging' => true` in the db settings of your config file) you can see that Yii queries the database frequently for ActiveRecord queries.

For example: Say you have a model named `User` and you tell Yii to get you a user by primary key, Yii will query the database three(!) times. It will do a `show columns` query, then a `show create table` query, then finally it will query the database for the actual data. Those first two queries are so Yii knows the schema of your `user` table. If the round trip time from your application server to your database server is 100ms (if it's really this slow, you should do something about it), then those two queries to get the schema will add a minimum of 200ms to your application response time. It will do this for every single request that populates your `User` model. Depending on how your application is written, it might even do that multiple times in a single request.

If, on the other hand, you tell Yii to use schema caching, Yii will check the cache to see if it already knows the schema to your `user` table and if it does, it will use that instead of hitting the database. There is still latency involved in checking the cache, but hopefully it's less than or equal to the latency to the database server. Say you're using a Redis server for caching and it also has a latency of 100ms (also ridiculously long). Caching the schema will still be faster than querying the database, because Yii will only need to query the cache a single time to retrieve the schema, versus two trips to the database.

So in this example switching from querying a high latency database for the schema to querying a high latency cache server will still save you time. In practice, your cache should be much lower latency than your database and therefore save you much more time and if your application is remotely complicated, Yii will be loading schema from multiple tables on each request so schema caching can make a huge difference in request response time.

Comment: How do you manually flush the schema cache? I think my production server is caching the schema for a table. I ran a migration to add a column, but when I try to set the field, it complains `Error: Setting unknown property: app\models\AdGroupKeywordNetwork::ebay_revenue`. It works in development.

Comment: I found the answer! `Yii::$app->cache->flush();` I pointed my DEV to PROD and can run that in a simple console command.

Comment: I'm going to bookmark this comment. You can also flush the cache directly in Redis: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6851929/148844

Answer (score 0):

If you were to enable the [weblog](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging) you would see that `CActiveRecord` objects read their respective table schemas on each application run. You can look through the code for [`CActiveRecord::_construct()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#__construct-detail) and [`CActiveRecordMetaData::__construct()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecordMetaData#__construct-detail) to see how this is done. Caching the schemas reduces the number of calls to the database, which in turn speeds up your application since the database is usually the application bottleneck.