# How to clear Azure Redis Cache?

Tags: caching, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I would like to know how to clear Azure Redis Cache from portal or any other easy way to clear all the keys ? I am using azure redis cache for my azure cloud service and I would like to know any easy way to clear all the keys for my azure redis cache. I couldn't find anything on the azure portal or the web on how to do this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Azure Redis cache is just standard Redis cache hosted in Azure so advice that applies to Redis applies here.  There isn't a feature in Azure to allow you to purge all keys or flush the DB but you can find samples online that show you how to do this, or use one of the tools listed on the Redis site: http://redis.io/clients

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete everything in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851909/how-do-i-delete-everything-in-redis)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The cache is cleared using standard Redis commands, like [FLUSHALL](http://redis.io/commands/FLUSHALL).  You can issue the command from any client, like redis-cli.exe or StackExchange.Redis.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Azure Redis Console to run FLUSHALL.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting Redis cache did the trick for me. Be sure to select both - master and slave for the reboot.

[image: Redis Reboot Options Screenshot]