# Flush/Empty db in StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md) in my application to store key/values. I need to flush the entire db now which Redis is using. I found a way via command
[How do I delete everything in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851909/how-do-i-delete-everything-in-redis)
but how can I do this with StackExchange.Redis? I was not able to find any method for that?

I searched for Empty, RemoveAll etc on IDatabase object and found nothing.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The easiest way is to use FlushDatabase method or FlushDatabaseAsync from IServer

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost,allowAdmin=true");
var server = redis.GetServer("localhost");
server.FlushDatabase();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this via some command line tool? I'd hate to have to write code just to flush the cache during development...

Comment: sure, you can do this in via redis-cli.exe with the argument "flushall" to flush all data in redis or you can you "flushdb" just to flush the selected db. e.g. if you need to flush db 1 you the next commands - "select 1" to select db with index 1, "flushdb" to flush only selected db. please note, the default db index is 0

Comment: @cesar-moya you can also use the "Redis Desktop Manager" (free windows app) see: https://redisdesktop.com/download

Comment: Is says "This operation is not available unless admin mode is enabled: FLUSHALL".

Comment: Make sure you set allowAdmin=true in the config string (or ConfigurationOptions).

Comment: The specified endpoint is not defined (Parameter 'endpoint')