# Where is the FLUSHALL command in http://try.redis.io/?

Tags: redis

I am learning Redis right now and one of the first things I did was trying to interactively issue commands to an online Redis server: http://try.redis.io/

The FLUSHALL command is well documented here: http://redis.io/commands/flushall and is also referenced in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6851929).

But when I try to issue it, it is simply not recognized:

[image]

My question: Why? Where has it disappeared? After all, the documentation says it is:

> "Available since 1.0.0."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web interface at try.redis.io, while executing against a real Redis database, offers only a subset of the actual commands. Because the database is shared by all users of the interface, some commands (`FLUSHALL` for example) are disabled in it.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Accepting +1.