# Clear Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, stackexchange.redis

Due to some issue where I need to clear all the cache data on the Redis cache hosted on the Azure.In other words by using the Azure portal.Not by using my application.One option I can think of is,Delete the Redis cache instance and recreate it.But do you know better way for doing that ? I'm using `StackExchange.Redis.dll`

**Update 2 :**

Could you tell me how to get `public key in PEM format` ? On the [**doc here**](http://docs.redisdesktop.com/en/latest/quick-start/) it says this `The easiest way to run this command in Windows - MSYS2`.I don't have any idea about that.

[image]

**Update 1 :**

Could you tell me why this is happening when I use the `redis-cli` ?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible in Azure Portal. However, you can use [redis-cli](http://redis.io/topics/rediscli) to issue [FLUSHDB](http://redis.io/commands/FLUSHDB) command. See This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851909/how-do-i-delete-everything-in-redis.

Comment: @qbik Yes,but how can I run those commands on azure portal ? How to connect redis db on the azure from my local machine ? Is there any GUI where I can use it ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For Azure's Redis service, the Azure portal has a built-in console (which is in Preview):

[image: console button]

At this point, it's as simple as executing a `flushall` command:

[image: flushall]

If you're running Redis in, say, a VM, you'll need to use a tool to connect remotely to the cache and run the `flushall` command.

Comment: for me it's disabled.do you know why ?

Comment: @Sampath The console is available for Standard and Premium tiers. If yours is disabled, you're likely running Basic tier. Here's the [faq](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-faq/) which calls this out. As I stated in my answer - if you use a local redis tool on your computer that supports console, you can then issue commands that way, just by connecting to your Azure Redis cache with credentials provided in the portal.

Comment: This is really BAD.The Basic tier is for the Development and Testing.We need `console` mostly on that stage.But you guys have disabled it for the most needed tier.Which is disappointing :( Anyway I have updated the question.Can I have a feedback for that too ?

Comment: @Sampath First: I'm not part of "you guys" - I don't work on the Azure product team. Second: The feature you seek is freely available via desktop tool (a simple search for `redis desktop manager` should enlighten you) - there is nothing stopping you from doing what you need to do, today, without a portal-based console.

Comment: Aha..I thought you're also a member of that product team.Anyway thanks for the clarification :) I have updated the question. Please see the `Update 2` section.

Comment: This must have changed at some point as the console is currently available for me in the basic tier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gbnz.redis-cache-clear

which is a basic devops extension. Use '*' in the value, it will flush all redis data