# How to delete everything in a redis cluster?

Tags: redis

My redis cluster is borked. One node seems to think it's a 3-node cluster with no replication, another node seems to think it's alone, and the third node agrees with the first. I want to have a 3-node cluster with 2 replicated nodes (no splitting).

I don't want to have to figure out how to un-bork my redis cluster, instead: I want to start over.

The existing question [How do I delete everything in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851909/how-do-i-delete-everything-in-redis) doesn't include clusters, for which everything is way more complicated.

Desired result: Clean installation. No cluster config.

Unfortunately simply reinstalling the whole program appears insufficient. How do I tell it to really `--yes-I-am-really-sure` forget everything about itself and all the other nodes it knows? In particular:

- Remove all non-config-file-cluster-configuration.

The command `CLUSTER FORGET` gets me partway there, but nodes can't forget themselves? Why not? Anyway, somehow convincing them to do that might be enough.

Answer (score 4):

The difficult part is in realizing these three things:

1. There's both `redis-cli CLUSTER` and `redis-cli --cluster`, and the cluster commands are randomly divided between the two.
2. When using`redis-cli --cluster` for something involving two nodes, the `-a` password parameter must be provided twice, both before and after the `--cluster` part. The one provided after is for the target node, the one provided before is for the 'config' node.
3. Commands using `redis CLUSTER` only apply to one node, so must be repeated for each node. (They cannot access the other nodes)

Knowing this, we can proceed wiping the necessary things:

```
 redis-cli -h host01 -a password CLUSTER NODES
```

prints a list of nodes with long identifiers.  Proceed with

```
# forget about the other nodes in the cluster on each node
redis-cli -h host01 -a password1 CLUSTER FORGET <host02 key> 
redis-cli -h host01 -a password1 CLUSTER FORGET <host03 key> 

redis-cli -h host02 -a password2 CLUSTER FORGET <host01 key> 
redis-cli -h host02 -a password2 CLUSTER FORGET <host03 key> 

redis-cli -h host03 -a password3 CLUSTER FORGET <host01 key> 
redis-cli -h host03 -a password3 CLUSTER FORGET <host02 key> 
# flush all data so that the node can be reset
redis-cli -h host01 -a password1 FLUSHALL
redis-cli -h host02 -a password2 FLUSHALL
redis-cli -h host03 -a password3 FLUSHALL
# reset the node 
redis-cli -h host01 -a password1 CLUSTER RESET
redis-cli -h host02 -a password2 CLUSTER RESET
redis-cli -h host03 -a password3 CLUSTER RESET
```

Comment: You can also do `redis-cli --cluster call host01 FLUSHALL` for example